# CheckBox.setChecked() is getting executed but not shown on screen

Tags: android, checkbox

I am using an onClickListener on a textview to setCheck() on a checkbox and saving the one value while clearing the last checked item in `itemStateArray` which is a SparseBooleanArray. The code is getting executed but the check box being checked is not shown.

```
textView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            if (!itemStateArray.get(adapterPosition, false)) {
                if (first) {
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    first = false;
                    lastChecked = checkBox;
                } else {
                    if (checkBox.isChecked() && lastChecked != null) {
                        lastChecked.setChecked(false);
                        checkBox.setChecked(true);
                        lastChecked = checkBox;
                    }
                }
                itemStateArray.clear();
                itemStateArray.put(adapterPosition, true);

            } else {
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
                itemStateArray.clear();
                itemStateArray.put(adapterPosition, false);

            }
        });
```

I am setting the listener on the textview as I want to click on the larger textview as compared the smaller checkbox on the side of the screen.

**Upon clicking the item and scrolling down and back up, the item is shown as checked.** I am setting the checkbox as checked in the onBindViewHolder
with the following code:

```
holder.bind(position);
```

The bind function to which I am passing the checked positions:

```
void bind(int position) {
            if (!itemStateArray.get(position, false)) {
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
                lastChecked = checkBox;
            }
        }
```

the checkbox being animated is not shown on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with a listView/RecyclerView right?
I think that the best way to achieve this is telling the view to refresh that line using the method

```
recyclerView.notifyItemChanged(int)
```

where int is the position of the row where che checkbox is being toggled.